# Timers not running synchronously from central timestamp

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm creating a game with a central timestamp set in a database. User 1 starts the game and the timestamp gets send to the database. Both players have a timer running in their apps, running 1 gametimer and 1 update timer.

**Player 1:**
Lets say the timestamp set by user 1 is: `20:00:00`.
Then the game runs until `22:00:00`.
And the next update will be on `20:15:00`. ***(after 15 minutes another 15 minutes will be added)***

**Player 2**
Player 2 gets exactly the same timestamp from the database: `20:00:00`
Player 2 also adds **15 minutes** to the central timestamp. `20:15:00`
And the game endtime also is the central timestamp +2 hours `22:00:00`

But now the issue:

Even when the timestamp is the same on both devices, the timer runs behind 3-4 seconds atleast. How is this possible when both timers are oriented on the same timestamp? The timer interval is set on 100ms.

The code im using:

**Player 1:**

```
private void InitializeTimer()
{
    StartTime = CurrentGame.StartTime.Value;
    EndTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(CurrentSettings.TotalGameTime); // added 120 minutes
    NextUpdateTime = StartTime.AddSeconds(CurrentSettings.LocationTimePlayers); // added 15 minutes
    NextUpdateTimeAdmin = StartTime.AddSeconds(CurrentSettings.LocatonTimeAdmin); // added 1 minute

    GameTimer = new Timer();
    GameTimer.Interval = 100;
    GameTimer.Elapsed += GameTimer_Elapsed;
    GameTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

**Player 2:**

```
private void InitializeGameTimer()
{
    StartTime = CurrentGame.StartTime.Value;
    EndTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(CurrentSettings.TotalGameTime); //added 120 minutes
    NextUpdateTime = StartTime.AddSeconds(CurrentSettings.LocationTimePlayers); //added 15 minutes

    GameTimer = new Timer();
    GameTimer.Interval = 100;
    GameTimer.Elapsed += GameTimer_Elapsed;
    GameTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Can somebody please point me in a direction? I'm really getting stuck on this.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT, added elapsed event used on both devices.**

```
public void GameTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (now >= NextUpdateTime)
    {
        this.StartSearchingForLocationUpdates(this, null);
        //Restart updatetimer(add 15 minutes again)
        NextUpdateTime = NextUpdateTime.AddSeconds(CurrentSettings.LocationTimePlayers);
    }

    EndGameTimeSpan = EndTime.Subtract(now);// amount of gametime left, will be shown on UI
    NextUpdateTimeSpan = NextUpdateTime.Subtract(now);// time till next update, will be shown on UI

    this.GameTimerElapsed(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Added some code to post :)

Comment: So you start the timer when you receive the values? If so, it could already be a problem of the time necessary retrieving the values from the database. Try retrieving the data in advance and then waiting for the time to start the timers

Comment: All data is gathered before starting the timers, on both activities. Sometimes the timer of player 1 shows up on the ui with just 1:59:55 to go because of that. Same case with player 2. but with a central timestamp that shouldn't be the issue right?

Comment: Instead of a "timer" to be the source of the time (you will always have time drift due to the multiple factors), use the actual realtime clock on the device as an offset to the central/common timestamp and use the continuously updated realtime clock offset value in a timer/loop/etc. so you are not dependent on the execution delay of the timer and its surrounding code.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'll add my code in the elapsed event. I'm using DateTime.Now to substract the timestamp from. To get the amount of time left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! The current time on one device runs behind 5 seconds. So it's not my code causing the issue, but the phone is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a System.Timers.Timer or a System.Windows.Forms.Timer?  The first will execute on time (or close to it, depending on clock resolution you may be 15 or so milliseconds off).  The second will execute on time IF there are no other window messages to parse at that time.  For a game, you almost certainly want the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't know the difference. But I'm using a System.Timers timer :)